# Rendering a view of hierarchical lists with unknown/unlimited nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following pattern is a set of lists nested within other list items.

```
<ul id="nestedlist">
  <li><a href="#"> 1</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> 1.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="connect"><a href="#"> 1.2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.2.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.2.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> 1.2.5</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"> 1.2.5.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> 1.2.5.2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#"> 1.2.5.2.1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"> 1.2.5.2.2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> 1.2.5.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The model `Node`

```
belongs_to :parentnode
has_many :children_nodes, foreign_key: :parentnode_id, class_name: 'Parentnode'
```

Thus an unlimited number of levels can be defined in a hierarchy.

The view rendering is essential a pattern where each node can become a parentnode

```
Parentnode.children_nodes.each_with_index do |node, index|
  node.name
  **parent_indicies.(index + 1)**
end
```

How can this be rendered in a rails view to represent each node level and its nesting level when the nesting levels are not known beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails helper methods to generate rails view.

Example:

```
content_tag(:ul) do
  (1..10).each do |node|
    concat content_tag(:li, node)
  end
end
```

And the logic would be to use recursion:

```
def generate_list(node, level)
  return if node == nil

  #put logic of generating ul li here.
  #add ul if node.children_nodes.present?
  #else add li.

  node.children_nodes.each_with_index |node, index|
    generate_list(node, "#{level}.#{index+1}"
  end
end
```

This is just the base logic. I hope you can do the rest of the part. If you still face difficulty just let me know.

Updated with below working code to generate html:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :val, :children_nodes

  def initialize(value)
    self.val = value
    self.children_nodes = []
  end

end

p1 = Node.new("P")
n1 = Node.new("1")
n2 = Node.new("2")
p1.children_nodes.push(n1)
p1.children_nodes.push(n2)

def generate_list(node, level, final_str)
  return if node == nil

  if node.children_nodes.size > 0
    final_str << "<li> #{node.val}"
    final_str << "<ul> "
  else
    final_str << "<li> #{node.val} </li>"
  end

  node.children_nodes.each_with_index do |n, index|
    generate_list(n, "#{level}.#{index+1}", final_str)
  end

  if node.children_nodes.size > 0
    final_str << "</ul> "
    final_str << "</li>"
  end
end


def generate(node)
  final_str = ""
  final_str << "<ul>"
  generate_list(node, 1, final_str)
  final_str << "</ul>"

  final_str
end

puts generate(p1)
```

Comment: This is useful, however it does not reflect the nature of the unknown nest levels `(1..10)`.  I stumbled into another method, simply bay calling a partial nested within the partial to handle that.  This may end up requiring cacheing and possibly some sidekiq job to process off line.

Comment: (1..10) was just an example, Let me update the answer for you. If you'll create a sidekiq job then how often you're going to run it?

Comment: When a new record is added to a node.